# foreach doesn't work with array created by getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom

when i create array by collecting the buttons in the web page using document.getElementsByTagName i can't use forEach
for Ex

```
    var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    deleteButtons.forEach(deleteButtons => {
        deleteButtons.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            e.target.parentElement().remove();
        })
    })
```

it gives me error `Uncaught TypeError: deleteButtons.forEach is not a function`
**but when i use querySelectorAll it works!**
})

Comment: Use `var deleteButtons = [...document.getElementsByTagName("button")];` to create an array.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which doesn't have a `forEach` method. While `querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).which has the `forEach` method

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which doesn't have a `forEach` method. While `querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).which has the `forEach` method.

To make it work you need to change the HTMLCollection into an Array, which can be done like so:

```
var deleteButtons = [...document.getElementsByTagName("button")];
```

or:

```
var deleteButtons = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an array. It returns a *live* [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

However HTMLCollections are iterable, so you can easily convert it into an array.

```js
const collection = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

const array = [...collection];

array.forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**deleteButtons** is a HTMLCollection, not an array. You can use:

```
ar arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( deleteButtons )
```

to convert in into an array and than it is possible to iterate over it.